# indifferent to and indifferent about

Tags: grammar, grammaticality, grammaticality-in-context

Is **to** and **about** interchange in this context?

I  was indifferent ***to*** the subject.

or

I  was indifferent ***about*** the subject.

Answer (score 1):

In this specific sentence, the two words "to" and "about" are interchangeable.

Technically, "to" could state that you are indifferent to "this exact subject with clearly defined boundaries" while "about" could state that you are indifferent to "this subject and things closely related to it", however *in practice* people will not really make this distinction, and the sentences share the same meaning.

Answer (score 1):

In descending order of "popularity", [prepositions likely to occur](https://books.google.com/ngrams/graph?content=indifferent%20*%20the%20matter&year_start=1919&year_end=2019&corpus=26&smoothing=3) after ***indifferent*** are...

**to

in

about

on

concerning

toward

upon

regarding

over**

[image]

I see no good reason to suggest the choice between the above possibilities makes any difference to the ***meaning***. It really is just a ***stylistic choice***. Use whatever makes most sense to you, and it'll be easier to remember (or use ***to*** if you really have no personal preference).